# 1999 Honda Civic Dx Won't Start, No crank

Tags: honda, starting, civic, ignition, no-crank-no-start

My 1999 Honda Civic DX won't start. I there is no crank so I started by checking the starter solenoid, there is no signal. Then I checked all fuses and relays including the main relay and they are all good. What do you think I should check next?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please explain how you performed the checks you have done so far.

Comment: Is your car manual or automatic?

Answer (score 0):

here are 2 diagrams to help you, first is for an automatic, second is for a manual trans.[image]
[image]